# Is it best practice to install client tools (like Oracle SQL Developer) on the database server or another machine?

Tags: oracle-12c, best-practices, oracle-sql-developer

A company doing a code review asked for credentials to an Oracle database server. They logged in but soon came back asking where SQL Developer was located, stating that they couldn't find it in the "usual location". My DBA told them we never install client tools on the DB server and that they needed to install it on their own client. Which is best practice?

Comment: I don't see the point in not installing them on the server (actually I don't think you can install the server without SQL\*Plus) - but there is nothing wrong with that approach. For one, only very few people should have direct access to the database server. I would question why someone needs _direct_ access (login) to the DB server just to do a code review. Simply connecting to the database from any client should be more then enough. For a code review you theoretically don't even need database access. Access to the version control system storing the sources should be sufficient

Answer (score 3):

Best practice would be to install and use it from client machines, since every tool running on the server is consuming some resources which will not be available to the Oracle server

Installing it on the server -- probably no penalty as pointed out in the comments

Comment: A tool that is merely _installed_ does not consume any resources (other then hard disk space)  and will definitely not impact the Oracle server in any.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't see a reason to install it there tho, either. For dba purposes sqlplus is enough, and there shouldn't be anyone else anyway, just like You've pointed out.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Fair enough..  I used install as synonymous to run..